# How to make wine find mscoree.dll?

Tags: kali-linux, wine

I'm getting this when I try to load up some PE binary for a cracking game under Kali.

Getting it to run at all isn't part of the challenge.

```
0009:err:module:fixup_imports_ilonly mscoree.dll not found, IL-only binary L"test.exe" cannot be loaded.
```

However, I do have:

```
$ find / -iname "*mscoree.dll*" 2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/mscoree.dll.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/fakedlls/mscoree.dll
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/mscoree.dll.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/fakedlls/mscoree.dll
```

What is wrong?

I've been trying to fix this with various winetricks commands such as:

```
winetricks dotnet45

winetricks forcemono
```

Including installing mono-complete.

Comment: You'll need to find a way to tell wine where it should look for windows-services libraries. Also remember that Kali is [notoriously known as user unfriendly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399627/22886) - you may want to consider using another distribution.

Comment: As for closing this question - it doesn't seem to be about Windows internals - it seems to be a rather regular Wine question.

Comment: @peterph that does not help solve the question at all. Next time a friend has a problem with his BMW tell him to buy a Volkswagen instead, see how helpful that is.

Comment: @JacobS.P. not entirely, rather next time that friend has a problem with his BMW he shouldn't be marking his questions as VW-related.

Comment: I wasn't referring to that particular comment

Answer (score 0):

Depending which flavor of Wine you use, you are asked if you want to install Mono. Mono includes what's needed for mscoree.dll to be installed and loaded. Otherwise dotnet35 or later from winetricks should provide the same library. There could also be a problem with your current prefix. Create a new one to make sure it works correctly.